# JavaScript/TypeScript: Convert UUID from most significant bits (MSB)/least significant bits (LSB) representation to string

Tags: javascript, java, typescript, protocol-buffers, uuid

To save space when passing UUIDs with Protocol Buffers, we send them using the MSB/LSB representation, two 64-bit `long` values.

```proto
message Uuid {
  sfixed64 msb = 1;
  sfixed64 lsb = 2;
}
```

These are simple to go to and from in Java,

```java
UUID id = UUID.fromString("eb66c416-4739-465b-9af3-9dc33ed8eef9");
long msb = id.getMostSignificantBits();
long lsb = id.getLeastSignificantBits();
System.out.println(msb + ", " + lsb);
  // -1484283427208739237, -7281302710629372167

System.out.println(new UUID(msb, lsb));
  // eb66c416-4739-465b-9af3-9dc33ed8eef9
```

However, since JavaScript's `number` only goes up to 2<sup>53</sup> - 1, I'm unable to convert the MSB/LSB format back to a `string` in my TypeScript client. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at Java `UUID`'s `toString()` method for inspiration,

```java
public String toString() {
  return (digits(mostSigBits >> 32, 8) + "-" +
    digits(mostSigBits >> 16, 4) + "-" +
    digits(mostSigBits, 4) + "-" +
    digits(leastSigBits >> 48, 4) + "-" +
    digits(leastSigBits, 12));
}

private static String digits(long val, int digits) {
  long hi = 1L << (digits * 4);
  return Long.toHexString(hi | (val & (hi - 1))).substring(1);
}
```

We can do the same using [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt). This assumes Node 10.8+ (tested with 18.14.0), TypeScript targeting ES2020+, and with [this browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt#browser_compatibility).

**Note**: If you get "BigInt literals are not available..." wrap all literals ending with `n` with `BigInt` instead (e.g., instead of `32n`, use `BigInt(32)`).

```js
function uuidSigBitsToStr({ lsb, msb }: { lsb: bigint; msb: bigint }): string {
  return `${digits(msb >> 32n, 8n)}-${digits(msb >> 16n, 4n)}-${digits(
    msb,
    4n
  )}-${digits(lsb >> 48n, 4n)}-${digits(lsb, 12n)}`;
}

function digits(val: bigint, ds: bigint): string {
  const hi = 1n << (ds * 4n);
  return (hi | (val & (hi - 1n))).toString(16).substring(1);
}
```

And an example test, notice msb/lsb are passed to `BigInt` as `string`s,

```js
it('converts UUID from msb/lsb to string', () => {
  expect(
    toUuidString(
      BigInt('-1160168401362026442'),
      BigInt('-6694969989912915968')
    )
  ).toEqual('a316b044-0157-1000-efe6-40fc5d2f0036');
});
```

The final piece is protocol buffers. By default, [`google-protobuf`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-protobuf) uses `number` for 64-bit `float` and `int` values, which causes overflow above `Number.MAX_VALUE` or 2<sup>53</sup> - 1. To avoid this, use the `jstype` annotation on 64-bit fields,

```
message Uuid {
    sfixed64 msb = 1 [jstype = JS_STRING];
    sfixed64 lsb = 2 [jstype = JS_STRING];
}
```

**2023 update: the reverse function, convert from UUID string to significant bits**

```js
function uuidStrToSigBits(uuid: string) {
  const invalidError = () => new Error(`Invalid UUID string: '${uuid}'`);
  if (uuid == null || typeof uuid !== "string") throw invalidError();

  const parts = uuid.split("-").map((p) => `0x${p}`);
  if (parts.length !== 5) throw invalidError();

  return {
    lsb: (hexStrToBigInt(parts[3]) << 48n) | hexStrToBigInt(parts[4]),
    msb:
      (hexStrToBigInt(parts[0]) << 32n) |
      (hexStrToBigInt(parts[1]) << 16n) |
      hexStrToBigInt(parts[2]),
  };
}

function hexStrToBigInt(hex: string): bigint {
  return BigInt(Number.parseInt(hex, 16));
}
```

Here's a round-trip test,

```js
const uuidSigBits = uuidStrToSigBits("7680fc63-1f58-412a-9bde-c5a9de1e0ce9");
const uuidStr = uuidSigBitsToStr(uuidSigBits);
console.log(uuidStr);
  // => 7680fc63-1f58-412a-9bde-c5a9de1e0ce9
```

Comment: Could you also provide a reverse function, one that will take in uuid string and output msb and lsb BigInt?

Comment: @IvanJakab, I added an update with the reverse function.