# Javascript equivalent of Java's UUID class

Tags: javascript, uuid, bitwise-operators

In java, you can do something like

```java
UUID id = UUID.fromString("eb66c416-4739-465b-9af3-9dc33ed8eef9");
long msb = id.getMostSignificantBits();
long lsb = id.getLeastSignificantBits();
System.out.println(msb + ", " + lsb);
  // -1484283427208739237, -7281302710629372167

System.out.println(new UUID(msb, lsb));
  // eb66c416-4739-465b-9af3-9dc33ed8eef9
```

This same example is referenced in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66304547/javascript-typescript-convert-uuid-from-most-significant-bits-msb-least-signi) which is pretty similar, so this would be a follow up. While in the related question problem of lsb, msb -> string was solved, I cannot find solution for reverse problem, string -> msb, lsb

The original solution was

```js
function toUuidString(lsb, msb) {
    return `${digits(msb >> 32n, 8n)}-${digits(msb >> 16n, 4n)}-${digits(
        msb,
        4n
    )}-${digits(lsb >> 48n, 4n)}-${digits(lsb, 12n)}`
}

function digits(value, ds) {
    const hi = 1n << (ds * 4n)

    return (hi | (value & (hi - 1n))).toString(16).slice(1)
}
```

Now I'd like to have a function that takes in string and returns msb and lsb.
Following original questions' paths, I've discovered [java source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/default/src/share/classes/java/util/UUID.java) and tried to do the equivalent, which would be:

```js
function fromString(name) {
    let components = name.split('-')

    if (components.length !== 5) {
        throw new Error(`Invalid UUID string: ${name}`)
    }

    for (let index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
        components[index] = `0x${components[index]}`
    }

    let mostSigBits = Number.parseInt(components[0], 16)
    mostSigBits <<= 16
    mostSigBits |= Number.parseInt(components[1], 16)
    mostSigBits <<= 16
    mostSigBits |= Number.parseInt(components[2], 16)

    let leastSigBits = Number.parseInt(components[3], 16)
    leastSigBits <<= 48
    leastSigBits |= Number.parseInt(components[4], 16)

    return {
        leastSigBits,
        mostSigBits,
    }
}
```

However, when I try to test this with something like:

```js
const originalUuid = 'eb66c416-4739-465b-9af3-9dc33ed8eef9'
const parts = fromString(originalUuid)

const newUUid = toUuidString(
    BigInt(parts.leastSigBits),
    BigInt(parts.mostSigBits)
)

console.log('Original', originalUuid)
console.log('New', newUUid)
```

I do not get equivalent uuids. They have equivalent parts but some parts are missing

```
Original eb66c416-4739-465b-9af3-9dc33ed8eef9
New 00000000-4739-465b-ffff-ffffbefbeef9
```

Any ideas what went wrong?

Comment: What is the reason you're using UUIDs at all? Why are you looking at the lsbs/msbs?

Comment: Similar to the original question, while transporting over protobuf we send uuids as msb and lsb pair. Overoptimization IMO, but here we are

Comment: There is no such thing as a long in javascript. The maximum safe integer size is (2^53)-1. If you're interfacing with a system that requires two longs, you should be looking into using UintArrays

Comment: @AndrewParks yes, but javascript has BigInt. While I did not go for UintArrays, your comment gave me an idea, and found an error - I needed to have mostSigBits as BigInt. Thanks, I'll be posting a solution

Comment: Your `toUuidString` code is working with BigInts. Your `fromString` code is missing that aspect (and this is the reason it doesn't work), `parseInt` returns normal (floating point double precision) numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I found the problem - two codes were not strictly equivalent, java source code declared mostSigBits and leastSigBits as long, which cannot be represented in javascript, so we need to use BigInt.

To sum up my question and previous question, javascript equivalent for java's UUID operations would be:

string -> msb, lsb

```js
function fromString(name) {
    let components = name.split('-')

    if (components.length !== 5) {
        throw new Error(`Invalid UUID string: ${name}`)
    }

    for (let index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
        components[index] = `0x${components[index]}`
    }

    let mostSigBits = BigInt(Number.parseInt(components[0], 16))
    mostSigBits <<= 16n
    mostSigBits |= BigInt(Number.parseInt(components[1], 16))
    mostSigBits <<= 16n
    mostSigBits |= BigInt(Number.parseInt(components[2], 16))

    let leastSigBits = BigInt(Number.parseInt(components[3], 16))
    leastSigBits <<= 48n
    leastSigBits |= BigInt(Number.parseInt(components[4], 16))

    return {
        leastSigBits,
        mostSigBits,
    }
}
```

msb, lsb -> string (from the referenced question)

```js
function toUuidString(lsb, msb) {
    return `${digits(msb >> 32n, 8n)}-${digits(msb >> 16n, 4n)}-${digits(
        msb,
        4n
    )}-${digits(lsb >> 48n, 4n)}-${digits(lsb, 12n)}`
}

function digits(value, ds) {
    const hi = 1n << (ds * 4n)

    return (hi | (value & (hi - 1n))).toString(16).slice(1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At JavaScript side, if the `(lsb, msb)->uuid` & `uuid->(lsb, msb)` both use the BigInt, then you don't need to consider the bit representation of the number itself.

```
function toUuidString(lsb, msb) {
  return `${digits(msb >> 32n, 8n)}-${
            digits(msb >> 16n, 4n)}-${
            digits(msb, 4n)}-${
            digits(lsb >> 48n, 4n)}-${digits(lsb, 12n)}`
}

function digits(value, ds) {
  const hi = 1n << (ds * 4n)
  return (hi | (value & (hi - 1n))).toString(16).slice(1)
}


function fromString(name) {
  let components = name.split('-')

  if (components.length !== 5) {
    throw new Error(`Invalid UUID string: ${name}`)
  }

  for (let index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
    components[index] = `0x${components[index]}`
  }

  let mostSigBits = BigInt(`${components[0]}`)
  mostSigBits <<= 16n
  mostSigBits |= BigInt(`${components[1]}`)
  mostSigBits <<= 16n
  mostSigBits |= BigInt(`${components[2]}`)

  let leastSigBits = BigInt(`${components[3]}`)
  leastSigBits <<= 48n
  leastSigBits |= BigInt(`${components[4]}`)

  return {
    leastSigBits,
    mostSigBits,
  }
}
```

---

But if you take the literal value from Java, say you got them from `getMostSignificantBits` and `getLeastSignificantBits`. Then you need to convert it to make sure its bytes are the same as what Java Long's representation bytes are (which are [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations?#Two%27s_complement) when the value is negative).

```
// assume x under range of signed long value
function unsignedBitShiftRight(x, n) {
  if (n === 0) { return x; }
  else if (x >= 0) { return x >> n; }
  // convert to two's complement and then do the shifting
  else { return (((1n << 64n) - 1n) ^ (- (x + 1n))) >> n; }
}
```

Replace the `>>` with `unsignedBitShiftRight`:

```
// lsb & msb taken from Java's getLeastSignificantBits & getMostSignificantBits
function toUuidString(lsb, msb) {
  return `${
    digits(unsignedBitShiftRight(msb, 32n), 8n)}-${
    digits(unsignedBitShiftRight(msb, 16n), 4n)}-${
    digits(msb, 4n)}-${
    digits(unsignedBitShiftRight(lsb, 48n), 4n)}-${
    digits(lsb, 12n)}`
}

function digits(value, ds) {
  const hi = 1n << (ds * 4n)
  return (hi | (value & (hi - 1n))).toString(16).slice(1)
}
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong with using `>>`?

Comment: `BigInt(-1) >> BigInt(4)` returns  `-1n`. Where the unsigned bit shift right `-1L >>> 4` returns `1152921504606846975`.

Comment: That's for signed longs, but surely uuids are unsigned?

Comment: @Bergi Both [`getMostSignificantBits()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/UUID.html#getMostSignificantBits()) and [`getLeastSignificantBits()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/UUID.html#getLeastSignificantBits()) return signed long values. This can also be concluded from the question since both return values are negative.

Comment: Ah, but that's just because Java doesn't support `unsigned long`, I doubt it makes sense to replicate that behaviour in JS

Comment: Hi, you're right, when you are in JavaScript world and dealing with BigInt, you don't need to consider the underlying byte representation of the number. Your original `fromString` should use the BigInt for the lsb & msb parsing.